# No getting header when adding logic - Angular 7

Tags: node.js, express, cors, authorization, angular7

I have this code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'); //
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {   
  console.log(req.headers.authorization);
  next(); 
});
```

I make a request like this

```
this.httpClient
  .get<any>('url', {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer token')
  })
  .subscribe(x => {

  });
```

And everything works great.

**Console: 'Bearer token'**

but if i add some logic like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {   
  console.log(req.headers.authorization);

  //LOGIC
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'NoAuthorization' });
    return;
  }

  next(); 
});
```

The suddenly

console.log(req.headers.authorization); 
undefined

and

[image]

WHY????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really hard to spot the error...

But i found it...

the problem was that for each request I'm getting two, because of the **pre-flight request** with method OPTIONS when making cross-origin request.

so i added

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { 
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');   
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');  
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

   //END when options... so the request can continue.
   if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      return res.status(200).end();   
   }
   next(); 
});
```

or if prefered, express support app.METHOD, including options... so you can

```
app.options("/*", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  res.send(200);
});
```

now is working fine!...

*(many hours looking for this problem.)*

Is there a better solution?